# character buffer object error in translate python

Tags: python, translate

```
  1 import sys
  2 import string
  3 from collections import Counter
  4 
  5 def count_words(input_file_path, *w_f):
  6     tab = dict.fromkeys([ord(i) for i in string.punctuation], u' ')
  7     words = []
  8     count = 0
  9     frequency = Counter()
 10     with open(input_file_path, "r") as fp:
 11         for line in fp.readlines():
 12             linei = line.translate(tab)
 13             words = linei.split()
 14             count += len(words)
 15             for item in words:
 16                 frequency[item] += 1
 17         if w_f:
 18             with open(w_f, "w") as wfp:
 19                 to_write = fp.read()
 20                 wfp.write(to_write)
 21 
 22     sorted(frequency.items())
 23     print "total word count %d" %  count
 24     print "Frequency "
 25     print frequency
 26 
 27 if __name__ == '__main__':
 28     if len(sys.argv) == 2:
 29         count_words(sys.argv[1])
 30     elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
 31          count_words(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
 32     else: raise Exception("Insufficient Arguments")
```

I've written a program to count words.
The error is a typeerror.
It says translate expects a buffer object .Its got to do with the unicode i guess.

What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation on `str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

> translate the characters using table, which **must be a 256-character string**

You're however trying to use a dict. To create a valid translation table, take a look at [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).

Comment: So instead i can just convert the dict to a string rite? @Rawing